# Custom Page Template utilizing Wordpress' Block Theme Editor

Tags: wordpress

i've been messing around with Gutenbergs new Site Editor tookit and building a block based theme. One thing I cannot for the life of me figure out though is how to set up a custom page global theme using the block editors .html template files. I can't seem to find any documentation either. For reference, this is the PHP code you add at the top if doing it "the old fashioned way:

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Full Width Page
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
* @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
*/
```

This signifies to wordpress that this is a page attribute theme that can be chosen. In contrast, here is what I have for a example in the new block editor:

```
<!-- wp:cover {"url":"http:\/\/wppld.local\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/bigstock-Panoramic-View-From-Cannon-Mou-195735793.jpg","id":18,"align":"full"} -->
<div class="wp-block-cover alignfull has-background-dim">
  <img
    class="wp-block-cover__image-background wp-image-18"
    alt=""
    src="http://wppld.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/bigstock-Panoramic-View-From-Cannon-Mou-195735793.jpg"
    data-object-fit="cover"
  />
  <div class="wp-block-cover__inner-container">
    <!-- wp:paragraph {"align":"center","placeholder":"Write title\u2026","fontSize":"large"} -->
    <p class="has-text-align-center has-large-font-size"></p>
    <!-- /wp:paragraph -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /wp:cover -->

<!-- wp:post-title /-->

<!-- wp:post-content /-->

<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"footer","align":"full"} /-->
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Gutenberg momentum is slow to take off. Gutenberg is the answer for WordPress to Shopify. They felt threatened by it and decided to switch to visual editing and push hard on their main income avenue, WordPress.com. The main focus is towards providing a service able to compete with Shopify.

There is (hidden) documentation, in regards to future plans WordPress has. With recent changes, for example, did you know that soon the main standard for WordPress development will be [Block-Based Design](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-based-theme/) ? Soon being in the next 3/5-ish years of course.

> Full site editing is an experimental feature and the workflow in this tutorial is likely to change.

It is still really early in development. It's the evolution WordPress is currently going for. Where you could supply [a set of blocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-based-theme/#creating-the-templates-and-template-parts) to use straight from the gecko, upon choosing a page template or for the landing page too.

But to be honest that's it. Even tho Gutenberg was introduced, it has not yet found it's placed.

Comment: Aw thats a bummer. Was hoping they had that kind of functionality in place. It's fun to mess around with atleast. Thanks for your reply.